# Concept - java and android

Tags: java, android, jar, portability, dalvik

> Android uses Java via [Dalvik Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)).

can I understand from this quote : Any [Java class file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) or any [jar file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) can run on any android device?

If no, why?

Comment: I know the `java.awt` can not uses in android, so the answer is **NO**

Comment: awt can't run because there's no implementation for it on android, maybe we can ask can any java code without a native component (pure java) run on android?

Comment: @Reek the `awt` package is just a counterexample

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but...

**1) YES,** you can import any `jar` file on any android application and run on any android device. because it's compiled on Java bytecode already, and now, it can run on `DVM`.

**2) NO,** you can't use any Java class file on android because some packages don't port on android API.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Although .apk files are somewhat simlar to .jar files Android reads them completly diffrently than windows for example. On top of that Android has its own API so you have alot of stuff that can be used only in android and you have alot of stuff that you cant use on android.